# Swift get URL with parameters

Tags: json, swift, url, parameters

I'm sure this is stupid simple for all you seasoned guys out there, but for beginners it is tough!

I'm basically populating a table with a url that displays a json list.

So I have this in on top:

```
super.viewDidLoad()
get_data_from_url("http://www.example.com/my_jsonfile.php")
```

The following code works fine with a simple url without parameters:

```
  func get_data_from_url(url:String)
{
    let httpMethod = "GET"
    let timeout = 15
    let url = NSURL(string: url)
    let urlRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!,
        cachePolicy: .ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData,
        timeoutInterval: 15.0)
    let queue = NSOperationQueue()
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(
        urlRequest,
        queue: queue,
        completionHandler: {(response: NSURLResponse!,
            data: NSData!,
            error: NSError!) in
            if data.length > 0 && error == nil{
                let json = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)
                self.extract_json(json!)
            }else if data.length == 0 && error == nil{
                println("Nothing was downloaded")
            } else if error != nil{
                println("Error happened = \(error)")
            }
        }
    )
}
```

However how can I get my parameters in there? i.e.: the url should be:

```
http://www.example.com/my_jsonfile.php?the_date=2015-05-16&leaving=yes
```

Comment: why can't you include the parameters in your call to `get_data_from_url`?

Comment: I tried adding it straight to get_data_from_url all in one line but it doesn't work. It doesn't crash or anything, but it just doesn't seem to pass along the get variables

Answer (score 1):

You have to concatenate the URL String, so that the parameters you want are in it:

```
var url = "http://www.example.com/my_jsonFile.php?"

var parameters = ["the_date=2015-05-16", "leaving=yes"]

for parameter in parameters{
  url+=parameter
  if parameter != parameters.last{
     url+="&"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show me how if you don't mind. I added all your code **before** my get_data_from_url function, and then changed my function to get_data_from_url(url) but that didn't help

Comment: What do you mean by "it didnt help"? the String you want to use as URL is in the url variable. Configure the parametersin the array and pass url to you function. If you still hve problems, please post the changed code

Comment: You were right. I had a typo in there. Thanks much!